# String from a function in C

Tags: c, string, function, return

Currently in the process of learning a bit of c, but I'm having issues with strings.

I simply want to return a string using a function. This is to be part of a bigger program that's supposed to get the word from an external file, but I want a simple function like this just to get going.

PS. Yes the bigger program is for school. I don't want to simply copy code, i want to understand it. Just throwing that out there.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

char* teststring()
{
    return (char*)"donald duck";
}

int main()
{
    char word[20];

    word = teststring();

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried various variations of returning a string, but my problem is that I'm unsure what to use as return type for the function and how to return it.

This is the most common error i get.

```
[Error] incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[20]' from type 'char *'
```

I've tried with different return types, declaring and initializing a char array and return it, and my latest test type conversion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Arrays can not be assigned to (except in a declaration initialization). Read about [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy).

Comment: `char *word;` or `strcpy(word, teststring());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd better add `const` modifier to the function `teststring()` as it returns a pointer to a const string. You cannot reassign `word` which is the address of `char[20]` to a pointer that points to a constant string. It must be copied.

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

const char* teststring()
{
    return "donald duck";
}

int main()
{
    char word[20];

    strcpy(word, teststring());
    printf("%s", word);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm using your function as is in my testing. And i just noticed that you moved the * after your edit? Wasn't it *teststring() before? Does it change anything?

Comment: @apelsin No, it makes no difference here. You can even put more spaces in between like `const char *  teststring()`. The compiler knows what you mean: Returning a pointer to a const string.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays (more properly, expressions of array type) cannot be the target of an assignment; you cannot copy the contents of one array to another using the `=` operator.

For strings, you will need to use either the `strcpy` or `strncpy` functions:

```
strcpy( word, teststring() ); // assumes word is large enough to hold the
                              // returned string.
```

For other arrays, use `memcpy`.

Comment: Okay this seem to be my main problem working with strings. Copy instead of assigning! So there's no way at all in c to assign an array with a value from a function. You have to copy to it or use pointers in the function?

Comment: @apelsin: Pretty much, yes. The reasons aren't *completely* arbitrary; see [this paper](http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/chist.html), particularly the section titled "Embryonic C", to understand why.

Comment: I'll read that tomorrow, I'm into deep in my code and it's getting late here. Thanks for your help.